# Passing list to PL/SQL procedure

Tags: python, oracle, plsql, cx-oracle, user-defined-types

There was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531760/how-to-pass-a-python-array-to-an-oracle-stored-procedure) some time ago. I tried to follow the advice's which results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST_ARRAY'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

This is what I have done so far.

**1. Create a new type**

```
create type list_ids as table of int;
```

**2. Create a test procedure**

```
create or replace procedure test_array(ids in list_ids) is
begin
    for i in 1..ids.count
    loop
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE(ids(i));
    end loop;
end;
```

**3. Running the python script**

```
import cx_Oracle


db = cx_Oracle.connect("my_user", "my_password", "<host>:<port>/<sid>")
cursor = db.cursor()

idl = cursor.arrayvar(cx_Oracle.NUMBER, [1,2,3,4])
cursor.callproc("test_array", parameters=[idl])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST_ARRAY'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: In [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35511658/1509264), the answers both use PL/SQL Associative Arrays (`TYPE name AS TABLE OF INT INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER`) and do not use SQL Collections as the data type being passed. This is almost certainly a duplicate of that question. The [documentation for `cursor.arrayvar`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.arrayvar) does not make it clear whether it only works for PL/SQL Associative Arrays or if it can also work for SQL Collections so I'll leave this open in case someone can post an example of the latter.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of differences between PL/SQL Associative Arrays and SQL Collections. That was the point I overlook (and was new to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments above, `cursor.arrayvar()` is only usable for PL/SQL associative arrays, not for nested tables. For nested tables you will need to use the "objects" API. This [example](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/PLSQLCollection.py) shows how to do so, even though it happens to be used for a PL/SQL associative array as well!

I have also adjusted the documentation of `cursor.arrayvar()` to make clear it is only usable for PL/SQL associative arrays with contiguous keys.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using the objects API is much more elegant than converting the associative array to a nested table within the procedure.